# .NET Regex.Matches behaves not as expected when finding multiple matches to pattern containing * ()

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My goal is to find all matches to some pattern in text.
Let's say my pattern is:

```
h.*o
```

This means I am searching for any text starting with `'h'` ending with `'o'` and having any number of chars in between (also zero).

My understanding was that method `Matches()` would deliver multiple matches according description (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/e7sf90t3.aspx)).

```
const string input = "hello hllo helo";
Regex regex = new Regex("h.*o");

var result = regex.Matches(input);
foreach (Match match in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

My expectation was:

```
1. "hello"
2. "hllo"
3. "helo"
4. "hello hllo"
5. "hello hllo helo"
```

To my surprise returned matches contain only one string - the whole input string.

```
"hello hllo helo"
```

**Questions:**

1. Which one is wrong: my expectation, my regex or usage of class?
2. How to achieve the result as shown in my example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` is *greedy* - it will try matching as many characters as it possibly could. You can make it *reluctant* by following it by question mark, but a better solution is to exclude `o` from the list if characters the `.` matches, like this:

```
h[^o]*o
```

Here is a [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) to very good explanation of greedy vs. reluctant.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that `*` is greedy, the `Matches` method only finds non-overlapping matches; that is, it looks for each subsequent match starting from the position where the last match left off. From [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9ee7wwd):

> Usually, the regular expression engine begins the search for the next match exactly where the previous match left off.

Thus, even if you used `*?` or `h[^o]*o` instead of `*`, it would still only find "hello", "hllo", and "helo".

I don't know if `Regex` has a built-in method to efficiently find *all* the possible substrings that match a specified pattern, but you could loop through all the possible substrings yourself and check if each one is a match:

```
const string input = "hello hllo helo";
Regex regex = new Regex("^h.*o$");

for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < input.Length - 1; startIndex++)
{
    for (int endIndex = startIndex + 1; endIndex <= input.Length; endIndex++)
    {
        string substring = input.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
        if (regex.IsMatch(substring))
            Console.WriteLine(substring);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hello
hello hllo
hello hllo helo
hllo
hllo helo
helo
```

Note that I added `^` and `$` to the regex to ensure it matches the entire `substring`, not just a substring of the `substring`.